# How to pass the Column name from the parent pipeline to child pipeline inside a foreach using execute pipeline in ADF

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am getting master pipelinethe output is below

```
 {
    "resultSetCount": 1,
    "recordsAffected": 21,
    "resultSets": [
        {
            "rowCount": 21,
            "rows": [
                {
                    "name": "EMPID",
                    "type": "NUMBER(12,0)",
                    "kind": "COLUMN",
                    "null?": "Y",
                    "default": null,
                    "primary key": "N",
                    "unique key": "N",
                    "check": null,
                    "expression": null,
                    "comment": "T",
                    "policy name": null,
                    "privacy domain": null
                },
                {
                    "name": "NAME",
                    "type": "VARCHAR(16777216)",
                    "kind": "COLUMN",
                    "null?": "Y",
                    "default": null,
                    "primary key": "N",
                    "unique key": "N",
                    "check": null,
                    "expression": null,
                    "comment": "The name of the tablespace this record comes from",
                    "policy name": null,
                    "privacy domain": null
                },
```

how do we pass the output of the script activity to the execute pipeline activity so that we can use this value in the child pipeline.

Comment: Could you add the pipeline code, now we only see the output, if I am right?

Answer (score 0):

To pass the script activity output to child pipeline, you need to use child pipeline parameters.

As the script activity output is of `JSON Object` type, create a parameter of type `Object` in the child pipeline.

[image]

Now, in the parent pipeline, take an Execute pipeline activity and add the child pipeline. Here, it will show the parameter of child pipeline. Pass the script activity output to this parameter like below. Here, I did this in pipeline directly. You need to do this inside the for-loop in your case.

```
@activity('Script1').output
```

[image]

Give your activities in the child pipeline. For sample, I have used an array type set variable activity in it and I have given the `rows` array from Script activity output to it using below expression.

```
@pipeline().parameters.script_output.resultSets[0].rows
```

Debug the parent pipeline and the output will be passed to the child pipeline. You can see that in the Execute pipeline input.

[image]

**Child pipeline Execution result:**

[image]

If you want to pass array from the activity output, you need to create array type parameter in the child pipeline and give the dynamic expression as per that.